# how to give query in has_many through association Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have following association

```
Mobile.rb
has_many :mobile_networks, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :networks, :through => :mobile_networks

Network.rb
has_many :mobiles, :through => :mobile_networks


MobileNetwork.rb
belongs_to :mobile
belongs_to :network
```

I want to query all mobile_networks of mobile and after that I want to check all network whether it is active or not something like I have written this code in my helper where I am getting mobile

```
    def mobile_state(mobile)
      mobile.mobile_networks.each do |e|
        e.network.is_checked #true
      end
   end
```

So i need to do this in a query. Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: `mobile.networks.map(&:is_checked)` try this

Comment: I need a condition if mobile.networks.where(:ischecked =true)end something like this

Comment: `Mobile.includes(:networks).where(id: params[:id]).where('is_checked = ?', true)` **OR**  `Mobile.includes(:networks).where(id: params[:id], networks: {is_checked: true})`

Comment: not working it gives me error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `includes' for #<Mobile:0xddfdbf0>):

Comment: instead of includes use joins

Comment: No its not working I have tried like this : `mobile.joins(:networks).where('is_checked = ?', true)` and got this error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `joins' for #<Mobile:0xbf068dc>)`

Comment: `Mobile.includes(:networks).where(id: params[:id], networks: {is_checked: true})`

Comment: If you use conditions with includes, you will need to use .references(:networks) here is the doc http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: Please got through question once

Comment: I think your question is not clear. You want to do what you have in your helper but in a query? Can you be more specific about what you'll do with your networks once you've got them? Maybe a simple .group clause can help you here?

Comment: you are using my given query with instance and which will not run

Comment: Yup I had tried all your comments and answer but still I am getting undefined method `includes' this error

Comment: `Mobile.joins(:networks).where(id: params[:id], networks: {is_checked: true})` is it working/

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
Mobile.joins(:networks).where(id: params[:id]).each do |m|
  m.networks.map(&:is_checked?)
end
```

Comment: I think that he wants just all the networks and after the query, he wants to check if each of the network is checked or not. If that so, just remove the where condition and use the helper of the question that should work.

Comment: @codingaddicted lmk if you think this is what he means. You seem to understand the vagueness of this question better than I do.

Comment: the art of questioning is complex. Still, I'm not sure to understand this one even if it seems an easy one! I vote up for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
MobileNetwork.mobiles(params[:id]).joins(:network).merge(Network.checked)

class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :checked -> {
    where(is_checked: true)
  }
end

class MobileNetwork < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :mobiles, ->(*m) {
    where(mobile_id: m.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }
end
```